# Convert xls to pdf using command prompt

Tags: command-line, pdf, prompt, xls

I have to convert a lot of .xls and .xlsx files to .pdf files. Is there a way to convert faster all the files using the command prompt?

Comment: I have done scripted PDF conversion before. Can you give more info on what you are working with? I have used PDFsharp, ghostscript, and powershell to create a couple solutions.

Comment: @CoryKnutson: I would be interested in how you have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward with Acrobat.

Follow these two steps then read the [blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2009/03/batch-conversion-of-excel-to-pdf/)

1: Quit Excel if it is already open.

2: Choose File—> Create PDF from File and open the folder containing the Excel documents. Select them all and click OK.
credits: Adobe

2:Method.

CMD

1. Open Command Prompt

You need to do the followings:

Click Windows + R in your computer > type cmd.exe in pop edit-box > click OK

2. Input commands

note1: “….exe” – path of “doc2pdf.exe”, “….xls” – path of source XLS file, “….pdf” – path of objective PDF, –i – specify input file, –o – specify output file)

(note2: to get conversion from XLS file to PDF file started, please click enter in Command Prompt)

Credit: [pdfconverter](http://www.e-pdfconverter.com/blog/how-to-convert-xls-to-pdf-with-gui-and-command-line/)

Comment: Thanks, Frrank.  The original question was regarding command-prompt conversion, not in the GUI of a paid-for program.  Please rephrase your answer and improve it by stating the name of the product needed (Acrobat).

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Thank you for your advice, much appreciated.